# Return different text each time the form is submitted PHP

Tags: php

I have a form that writes an array to CSV, and then displays a password. Each time the form is used data is written to a new line in the CSV and the same password is displayed.

I would like to display a different password each time the form is submitted.

So the first time someone uses the form, their $name,$starttime,$endtime,$today,$message & @pwrd[0] are all written to the CSV, and then @pwrd[0] is displayed on the page.
The second time someone fills the form, their $name,$starttime,$endtime,$today,$message & @pwrd[1] are all written to the CSV, and then @pwrd[1] is displzyed on the page.

Essentially I want to give out different credentials to each visitor, and record their details each time. Ideally these creds are pulled from a fairly secure place, but an array,text file or CSV will do for this application..

Many Thanks in advance!! :)

```
<?php
//index.php

$error = '';
$name = '';
$starttime = '';
$endtime = '';
$timedate = 'timedate';
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");   
$message = '';
$pwrd = array("User1 / Password1", "User2 / Password2", "User3 / Password3");



function clean_text($string)
{
 $string = trim($string);
 $string = stripslashes($string);
 $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
 return $string;
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
 if(empty($_POST["name"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter your Name</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $name = clean_text($_POST["name"]);
  if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
  {
   $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Only letters and white space allowed</label></p>';
  }
 }

 if(empty($_POST["starttime"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Start Time and Date is required eg: 01/01/2020 08:00</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $starttime = clean_text($_POST["starttime"]);
 }

 if(empty($_POST["endtime"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Start Time and Date is required eg: 23/01/2020 18:00</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $endtime = clean_text($_POST["endtime"]);
 }

 if(empty($_POST["message"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Message is required</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $message = clean_text($_POST["message"]);
 }


 if($error == '')
 {
  $file_open = fopen("contact_data.csv", "a");
  $no_rows = count(file("contact_data.csv"));
  if($no_rows > 1)
  {
   $no_rows = ($no_rows - 1) + 1;
  }
  $form_data = array(
   'sr_no'  => $no_rows,
   'name'  => $name,
   'today' => $today,
   'starttime'  => $starttime,
   'endtime' => $endtime,
   'message' => $message,
   'pwrd' => $pwrd[0]
  );
  fputcsv($file_open, $form_data);
  $error = '<label class="text-success">The Temporary  login details are </label>';
  $name = '';
  $today = '';
  $starttime = '';
  $endtime = '';
  $message = '';
  $pwrd[0] = '';

 }
}




?>





<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Enter the temporary staff details below to receive login details</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <h2 align="center">Enter the temporary staff details below to receive login details</h2>
   <br />
   <div class="col-md-6" style="margin:0 auto; float:none;">
    <form method="post">
<!--     <h3 align="center">Contact Form</h3>   -->
     <br />
     <?php echo $error; ?>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter Temp Staff Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Full Name of Temporary Staff" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter Start Time & Date</label>
      <input type="text" name="starttime" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Start Time & Date, eg: 01/01/2020 08:00" value="<?php echo $starttime; ?>" />
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter Finish Time & Date</label>
      <input type="text" name="endtime" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Finish Time & Date, eg: 23/01/2020 18:00" value="<?php echo $endtime; ?>" />
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter Your Name</label>
      <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Name"><?php echo $message; ?></textarea>
     </div>


     <div class="form-group" align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>

<a href='index.php'>Back to Main page</a>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you not have a database?

Comment: you want to generate a random password, I assume?

Comment: _and then displays a password_ **How... Where??**

Comment: Thanks for the replies!
Mark Overton - I don't have any DB..
ADyson - I want to pre populate the credentials..
RiggsFolly I would like to display the password in a pop up box or alert, anywhere on the screen.

Comment: How about just generating a [`uniqid()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Comment: The creds need to be pre-populated.
It takes forever to get accounts created in an old system we run. we have random users all the time who need to use this old system as soon as they arrive(can;t wait for acc creation).
we can't trust staff with a list of generic username's as they just give the same account details to every person.
We need a different generic account 'temp01,temp02' etc.. to be given to each user and their details to be recorded in the csv.
This doesn't have to be secure, it just needs to force staff into a correct process, to afford some accountabillity..

Comment: Ah ok so basically you want to record who each existing username is currently allocated to?

Comment: @ADyson thats it.

Comment: I would say this will be **much** easier with a simple MySQL or SQLite database than a CSV file.

Comment: @ADyson thanks I will look into that. My coding skills are minimal, I was just trying to find the quickest route by butchering this form > csv I found.